# Device Ready not firing in Adobe Phone Gap Build

Tags: ios, cordova, build, phonegap-build

I've build a PhoneGap app including an ios platform using the Cordova CLI, as per this [tutorial](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/guide_cli_index.md.html).

I deployed the app the my iphone5 via xcode and verified that the onDeviceReady event was firing. I then created a build of the app using the Adobe Phone Gap Build service and deployed the build to my iphone using itunes. The onDeviceReady ready event did not fire on the deployed build.

I've referenced the [Preparing Your App for PhoneGap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/docs/app-overview) document. It seems some people who experienced a similar issue were able to fix if by removing references to a cordova.js file as per the instructions in the document (the document refers to a phonegap.js file which is no where to be found in my build, I"m guessing this the same thing as cordova.js).

Has anyone else, who gotten past this issue, suggest a fix?

Comment: Did you find a fix for this? Having the same issue myself :-(

Answer (score 1):

Yeah I think you need a

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

in your index.html. By the way when you have built with build.phonegap.com (which inserts the phonegap.js file) you can just scan the QR code on the page with your phone rather than mucking about with iTunes